# NextJS excecuting code client-side from server-side call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am currently using `getStaticProps` to fetch data server-side at build time, and pass it to my page component. I make the following call from the page component file:

```
    const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
        const page = await fetchPage({
            preview: context.preview,
            slug: context.params.slug.toString(),
        });

        return { props: { page: stringify(page) } };
    };
```

This (as validated by `console.log(typeof window)`) is correctly executed server-side. Likewise, the `fetchPage` call is server-side.

```
const fetchPage = async ({
      preview,
      id,
      slug,
    }: FetchEntryOptions): Promise<Entry<Contentful.IPageFields>> => {
      const contentfulClient = preview
        ? contentfulPreviewApiClient
        : contentfulDeliveryApiClient;
   
      let page: Entry<Contentful.IPageFields>;
   
      if (id) {
        page = await contentfulClient.getEntry(id);
      } else {
        const pageCollection: EntryCollection<Contentful.IPageFields> = await contentfulClient.getE      ntries(
          {
            content_type: "page",
            "fields.slug": slug,
          }
        );
   
   page = pageCollection.items?.[0];
  }
  
  return page;
};
```

However, `contentfulPreviewApiClient` and `contentfulDeliveryApiClient` are both initialized client side.

Full codebase [here](https://github.com/the-cook-company/marketing-website/tree/development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So wierd quirk: Declaring a constant `getStaticProps` function, then exporting it with the syntax `export {getStaticProps}` leads to this, while the syntax `export const getStaticProps = ...` does not. No idea why.